# Hyperparameter tuning of statsmodels quantile regression

Tags: python, hyperparameter, statsmodels, quantile-regression

I am working in statsmodels and I am trying to do linear quantile regression with the function `QuantReg`. I can however not figure out a way to tune any hyperparameters, to avoid overfitting, such as regularization.

An example is given below:

```
df_dum = pd.DataFrame(columns=['y','x1','x2'])
df_dum['y'] = np.random.normal(size=10)
df_dum['x1'] = np.random.normal(size=10)+2
df_dum['x2'] = np.random.normal(size=10)+10

df_train, df_test = np.split(df_dum, [int(0.8*len(df_dum))])

mod = QuantReg(df_train['y'], df_train[['x1','x2']]).fit(0.25)
mod.predict(df_test[['x1','x2']])
```

Any idea how to tune hyperparameters for this dummy example?

Comment: if it's linear, then why are you afraid of overwriting?

Comment: In normal linear regression, I would use regularization to prevent overfitting. So I am assuming that the same is applicable when doing quantile regression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quantile regression in statsmodels does not support regularization, but sklearn does https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.QuantileRegressor.html

regularization by augmentation of the dataset is also an option, although there might be some specific consideration for quantile regression.

if your question is how to fit a model that is predicting quantiles well, than the answer might be different than just use scikit-learn

Comment: I cannot seem to get QuantileRegressor to work in sklearn, which version are you running in which it works?

Comment: i never run it myself, i just found it in their documentation, i generally assume that sklearn things work. It says that it is from a development version of sklearn, so you will need to install that. I can't help you more with that. I think stack overflow is a better venue for questions about specific libraries

Comment: The sklearn implementation is very slow and RAM intensive compared to the statsmodel version. Sadly it seems the statsmodel version does not come with regularization.